# Is the command line suppose to print this out?

Tags: linux

I am doing my assignment and the question mentioned to key in these command lines in LXTerminal and asking what is the purpose of "^C" here

cat>INT108AAE.txt

Hello, my name is “YourName” and I love my Raspberry Pi.

^C

ls

cat INT108AAE.txt

I checked internet, the "cat>" mean concatenate and create a new text file that can be use to enter the subsequent text which is make sense to me as a beginner and a text file "INT108AAE.txt" is created in the folder but the text file also print the remaining text which is "^C ls cat INT108AAE"? This does not make much sense to me. I tried searching on internet what does the command line "^C" does in linux or raspberry pi but did not get any result and I know "ls" mean list which is another command line for linux. Just to clarify is this suppose to be the output result from these command lines? In case I wanted to quit the text file in LXTerminal and return to input command, what should I type?

I also searched for internet that propose to use the method below
Press the [Esc] key and type Shift + Z Z to save and exit or type Shift+ Z Q to exit without saving the changes made to the file but still it end up the text file copied all the command I typed in and did not exit?

Comment: `^C` is universally know as notation for holding the `ctrl` key down while typing `C` on the keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^C is shorthand for ctrl-c (meaning, hold ctrl, press c, and release both).
I wouldn't recommend exiting cat that way, you should use ctrl-d instead (which is end of file).

The sequence  esc shift+ZZ  is how you get out of the vi editor, which you are not using here, although you could.

Cat is my favorite editor, because it's the fastest editor.  It's a pain to fix things in it though.